# Overloading the input stream operator >>

Tags: c++

I am trying to overload the >> operator so that when the user inputs a fraction, cin would store the fraction into an Object of type Fraction.

Excerpt from header file:

```
// Calculator.h
friend istream &operator>>( istream &, Fraction &);

private:
    signed int numo; // fraction numerator
    signed int deno; // fraction denomenator
    char ch; // the '/' character
```

Excerpt from Implementation file:

```
 //Calculator.cpp

// insertion operator overloading
istream &operator>>( istream &input, Fraction fraction)
{
    input >> fraction.numo;
    input >> fraction.ch;
    input >>fraction.deno;

    return input; 
}
```

When I try to compile Calculator.cpp and compile a driver function inside another file, I run into many errors. Why is this not working? Please explain your answer thoroughly, I would like to learn.

UPDATE:

**Errors: variables, numo deno and ch are 'private'

Comment: So what are the errors, or do you want a spanking?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: Are those mutually exclusive?

Comment: Why do you save a forward-slash in the object?

Comment: `Why is this not working?` Goblins? Putin? @CaptainObvlious having a bad day? These all seem equally valid.

Comment: Probably these errors http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c83febbd048a14e?

Comment: `undefined reference to operator>>(std::istream&, Fraction&)`

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth For you...the spankings are just mutual :)

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a simple mismatch. The function that's declared as a friend takes a *reference* to a `Fraction` as its second parameter. The function you've implemented takes a fraction by value instead, so it's not a friend of the `Fraction` class. You want the version that takes a reference since when you use the function you normally want to pass a variable, and you want it to modify that variable.

I usually prefer to implement such things in place:

```
class Fraction { 

     friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, Fraction &f) { 
        return is >> f.numo >> f.ch >> f.deno;
     }

     // ...
};
```

Even though its body is inside the class definition, this is still a non-member function simply by virtue of the fact that it's declared as a `friend`.

Answer (score 0):

Andy in Calculator.h header file, you are using `Fraction&` (ref type) as function second argument. So in function definition it must be same, (don't use value type).

Prototype:

```
friend istream& operator>>(istream&, Fraction );
```

Function definition:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& input, Fraction& fraction)
{
    input >> fraction.numo;
    input >> fraction.ch;
    input >>fraction.deno;

    return input; 
}
```